# Create symlink in build directory -- NodeJS on build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, filesystems, symlink

I have a basic react structure:

-project-root

--- node_modules

--- public

--- src

they live in `/var/www/html/project-root`

I have a php API at `var/www/html/php-api`

Our php API we use for other applications that I want to include into the build for "onsite" API usage.  So my thought was to have a symlink created so that the api directory is available in the build directory when I do `sudo npm run build` to production.  Thus enabling me to make this call `axios.get('/api/v2/users')` and the api directory would symlink to `/var/www/html/php-api`.

I have followed the docs on [Node.js fs.symlink() Function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-symlink-function/), but this looks like it creates a symlink in the node filesystem only:

```
fs.symlink(__dirname + "\\api",
    "symlinkToDir", '/var/www/html/php-api', (err) => {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else {
            console.log("Symlink created");
            console.log("Symlink is a directory:",
                fs.statSync("symlinkToDir").isDirectory()
            );
        }
    });
```

I even thought of trying to hackishly throw a shell command on the tail of the build IE:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server/index.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject && ln -s /var/www/html/php-api/ /var/www/html/project-root/build/api"
  },
```

Am I going about this the wrong way?  The only other hackish idea I can come up with is a Linux cron job that keeps that link in the build directory .. I can't bring myself to do this .. Can someone help me do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer I could find was to add it into the `"build"` portion of `"scripts"` in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server/index.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build && ln -s /var/www/html/php-api /var/www/html/project-root/build/api",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```